# Any methods to obtain nether warts without natural generation?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Minecraft with a self-imposed world border as a challenge. I want to be be able to brew potions in this game, but the border does not contain any fortresses, bastions, or wart forests. Is there any way to obtain Nether Wart without being able rely on world generation? This is in Minecraft 1.18.1.

Comment: Is there a wart forest biome? Or do you mean warped forest?

Comment: I still don't understand how nether wart can spawn on warped forest =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. You can trade with piglins for fire res, and kill witches for potions of healing. Witches throw potions of weakness too, so you can use that to convert zombie villagers if that is why you want to make potions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get nether wart in your current state. But, you can get potion arrows by trading with fletcher villagers.